# Use of constant $e$ in $e^{i\theta}$ and $e^z$ (notation clarification)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, exponential-function

In Complex Analysis one defines: $$e^{i\theta}:=\cos \theta+i\sin\theta$$ and proves identities like $e^{i\theta}e^{i\phi}=e^{i(\theta+\phi)}$ etc, using basic trigonometry.

One also defines complex exponential function, call it, $E(\cdot)$, such that:
$$E(x+iy):=e^{x}e^{iy}=e^x\cos y+i e^x\sin y.$$
Like above, one proves identities like $E(z)E(w)=E(z+w)$ etc. It is interesting to note that $E(x+i0)=e^x$ so $E$ extends in the complex plane the real exponential funtion (so one may also extend the notation like $E(z)=e^z$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$).

I would like to point out the use of "e" on the above notations.

As far as I understand, and please feel free to correct me if I am wrong, the only place where $e$ is the famous Euler's constant is on $e^x$ in the definition of $E(\cdot).$ It seems to me that it is all the nice properties satisfied that make us use a base-power notation like $e^{i\theta}$ and $e^z$, instead of somehing like:
$$\varpi(\theta) ~~~\mathrm{or} ~~~\exp_\mathbb{C}(z),$$
respectively (in addition to the fact that $\exp$ works great in the real case, so we would like to extend t h i s function on the complex plane, instead of extending, for example, $2^x$). If so of course, from that point of view, one could say that "the Most Beautiful Mathematical Formula Ever" $$e^{i \pi}+1=0$$ is *almost* The Most Beautiful Mathematical Formula Ever.

Is it so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a need to define exponential functions of a complex variable. There are at least two approaches which don't distinguish at all between real and complex version. First is $\exp(z) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n/n!$ and second one is $\exp(z) =\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+(z/n))^n$. Using any of these definitions one can deduce all properties of exponential functions. And $e=\exp(1)$ comes up a specific value of this function. As far as algebra is concerned we can show $\exp(z) =e^z$ when $z\in\mathbb {Q} $. When $z\notin\mathbb {Q} $ then $\exp(z) =e^z$ is a definition of symbol $e^z$.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than go through a two step definition of $e^z$, you could define it as
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n} {n!} $$
Thus the definition $e^{i\theta} =\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ is in no way arbitrary, it is in fact the only way you can extend the real exponential $e^x$ to the complex plane and have it be differentiable.

If you plug $1$ into the uniform formula you get Euler's constant, and if you plug in $i\pi$ you get $-1$. Seems pretty natural to me.

Comment: In this, also well known, powerseries expression of $e^z$, the constant "e" that you used equals $2.77182...$ or is it rather a "wannabe the real constant $e$" symbol  (that since it works like $e$ in the real case etc, we better call it $e$)?

Comment: @Nikolaos You could say the same thing about $e^\pi$. Does it involve $e$? You could argue the only time the constant is "really" involved is for rational powers. $e^\pi$ is meaningless other than a continuous extension of the function on rationals.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout the $e$ value used in these formulas is the actual constant $e=2.718...$, rather than a complex equivalent to the real valued variant